# Ignore running unitTest in the test itself

Tags: java, junit4

It can be happened, that the the unit test cannot test properly due too system condition.
eg: another job is running, what locks a table what is used by a service what should be tested.

in this case the output of the test should not be SUCCESS nor FAIL...
it should be just like IGNORED

is there a way to set the unit test 'ignored' in the test itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want Assume from JUnit4. Look at this documentation http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assume.html